# Tikz picture object changes size on each beamer frame and causes picture and text positions to shift?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I am creating a beamer presentation with several slides that features a tikz picture above an item list. Because one of the objects changes size in the text picture on each slide, the text and the tikz picture shift position as I change slides. How can I keep the position of the text and the tikz picture fixed for all slides? I have attached an image of the problem and some tex code demonstrating it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\wl{2}
\def\wh{0.8}
\def\posx{210}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-50]
\draw[black,dashed] (0,0) --  (pi*\wl,0);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\posx,scale=1,transform shape]
\fill[black] (-2,-2) rectangle ++(4,4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{itemize}
\item This page has 3 lines
\item This page has 3 lines
\item This page has 3 lines
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}  

\begin{frame}[t]
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (-2,-2) rectangle ++(4,4);
\def\wl{2}
\def\wh{0.8}
\def\posx{210}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-50]
\draw[black,dashed] (0,0) --  (pi*\wl,0);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=\posx,scale=1,transform shape]
\fill[black] (-1,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{itemize}
\item This page has 2 lines
\item This page has 2 lines
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the dashed line and both squares (with different sizes) in a fixed position?

Comment: If you use `\begin{frame}[t]` instead of `\begin{frame}` the slides won't jump but of course if the pictures have different heights the texts will move.

Comment: You can use a transparent path just to make sure both figures have the same height. Use `\path (-2,-2) rectangle ++(4,4);` in the second figure and don't `draw` in the first, only fill it, to avoid different strokes.

Comment: @Sigur Ok I added the path command to the second frame however I'm not sure what you mean 'don't draw in the first' - what am I not supposed to draw? What command should I use in the first frame?

Comment: @csss, to fill both squares, use only `\fill[black] ... `

Comment: @Sigur The dashed line should not move between frames - the square should scale symmetrically about its center.

Comment: Ok I've just tried that now and the text is shifting a lot less but it still shifts a bit, and the dashed line still shifts also.

Comment: @csss, did you use `[t]` on frames as suggested? It is working here.

Comment: @Sigur I've just tried [t] in conjunction with your path command - this stops the dashed line and the square from shifting vertically, however the text still shifts vertically. If I use [t] without your path command there the line and the text both shift.

Comment: Well, `[t]` and `\fill` on both and `\path` on second is working here. Try to open the pdf and full screen it to see what happens when change page.

Comment: After you edited, I observed some difference. Insert the `path` in the second `scope` in the 2nd frame.

Comment: @Sigur Hmmm..strange that its working for you but not for me. I've edited the original post to use the code I'm using now with the path, fill and [t] commands. Does this code work for you?

Comment: @csss, see my previous comment.

Comment: @Sigur Excellent, it works perfectly now! Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @csss, good. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a shorter code, using `[t]` as frame option (suggested by @marmot), and faking a path on second slide with same size as the square from the first slide.

Also, using overlay specification, we can write everything inside a single `frame`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
\footnotesize

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\wl{2}
\def\wh{0.8}
\def\posx{210}

\begin{scope}[xshift=-50]
\draw[black,dashed] (0,0) --  (pi*\wl,0);
\end{scope}

\uncover<1>{
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\posx,scale=1,transform shape]
    \fill[black] (-2,-2) rectangle ++(4,4);
    \end{scope}
}
\uncover<2>{
    \begin{scope}[xshift=\posx,scale=1,transform shape]
    \fill[black] (-1,-1) rectangle ++(2,2);
    \path (-2,-2) rectangle ++(4,4);  %  <-- transparent path
\end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\only<1>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This page has 3 lines
        \item This page has 3 lines
        \item This page has 3 lines
    \end{itemize}
}
\only<2>{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This page has 2 lines
        \item This page has 2 lines
    \end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```